# How to visualize sfc_Multipolygon in Leaflet R?

Tags: r, leaflet, r-sf

I am trying to visualize countries as members of international organizations (EU and Commonwealth) in leaflet. I managed to plot them with base function plot() but in leaflet, technically, this should be feasible (I have seen on some pages, stating this) yet I have problems. The data.frame has multipolygon as geometry, whereas many examples I have found need long/lat coordinates.
How could I visualize countries in leaflet then?

```
library(sf)
library(jsonlite)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(knitr)

df <- fromJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieghernan/Country-Codes-and-International-Organizations/master/outputs/Countrycodesfull.json")

str(df)


orgsdb <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieghernan/Country-Codes-and-International-Organizations/master/outputs/CountrycodesOrgs.csv") %>%
  distinct(org_id, org_name)
str(orgsdb)


#Function----
ISO_memcol <- function(df,
                       orgtosearch) {
  ind <- match(orgtosearch, unlist(df[1, "org_id"]))
  or <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x)
    unlist(df[x, "org_member"])[ind])
  or <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(or)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  names(or) <- orgtosearch
  df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(df, or, stringsAsFactors = F))
  return(df2)
}
df_org <- ISO_memcol(df, "EU")


df_org <- ISO_memcol(df_org, "C")

df_org %>% count(EU) %>% kable(format = "markdown")


df_org%>%
  select(
    ISO_3166_3,
    NAME.EN,
    EU,
    C
  ) %>%
  kable(format = "markdown")


testmap <- ne_countries(50,
           "countries",
           returnclass = "sf") %>%
  select(ISO_3166_3 = adm0_a3) %>%
  full_join(df_org)

testmap_leaf <- st_transform(testmap, 4326)

m1<-leaflet(testmap_leaf)%>%
  addTiles()%>%
  addPolygons( )

m1
```

Answer (score 2):

you were really close, but there are a few things to note:

1. First, you are selecting all the countries of the world when doing `full_join(df_org)`
2. The function `ISO_memcol` returns all the countries **plus a column** indicating the membership of the country (note that I am the developer of that function :)).

So I took the liberty of modify the workflow a bit in order to create a choropleth.
There is a dataset here `df_org_all` with a column `org` indicating wheter the country is EU or Commonwealth (after Brexit there are no countries on both orgs,I think).

I also created a palette to display the membership in a final leaflet map. Hope this helps. Regards

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(jsonlite)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
#> 
#>     filter, lag
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(knitr)

df <- fromJSON("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieghernan/Country-Codes-and-International-Organizations/master/outputs/Countrycodesfull.json")

# str(df)


orgsdb <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dieghernan/Country-Codes-and-International-Organizations/master/outputs/CountrycodesOrgs.csv") %>%
  distinct(org_id, org_name)
# str(orgsdb)


# Function----
ISO_memcol <- function(df,
                       orgtosearch) {
  ind <- match(orgtosearch, unlist(df[1, "org_id"]))
  or <- lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) {
    unlist(df[x, "org_member"])[ind]
  })
  or <- data.frame(matrix(unlist(or)), stringsAsFactors = F)
  names(or) <- orgtosearch
  df2 <- as.data.frame(cbind(df, or, stringsAsFactors = F))
  return(df2)
}


# Mutate values
df_org_eu <- ISO_memcol(df, "EU") %>%
  filter(EU == "member") %>%
  mutate(org = "EU")
df_org_C <- ISO_memcol(df, "C") %>%
  filter(C == "member") %>%
  mutate(org = "Commonwealth")


# EU + Commonwealth

df_org_all <- df_org_eu %>%
  bind_rows(df_org_C) %>%
  select(
    ISO_3166_3,
    NAME.EN,
    org
  )


df_org_all %>%
  count(org) %>%
  kable(format = "markdown")
```

| org | n |
| --- | --- |
| Commonwealth | 53 |
| EU | 27 |

```r
testmap <- ne_countries(50,
  "countries",
  returnclass = "sf"
) %>%
  select(ISO_3166_3 = adm0_a3) %>%
  full_join(df_org_all)
#> Joining, by = "ISO_3166_3"


testmap_leaf <- st_transform(testmap, 4326)

pal <- colorFactor(palette = "viridis", domain = testmap$org)

m1 <- leaflet(testmap_leaf) %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addPolygons(fillColor = ~ pal(org), stroke = NA, fillOpacity = .7) %>%
  addLegend(pal = pal, values = ~org)

m1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-08-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: really appreciate this part: (note that I am the developer of that function :))

Comment: I really wanted to mean that, it is described here! https://github.com/dieghernan/Country-Codes-and-International-Organizations

Comment: and so did I! I find it really cool when the author of a piece of software finds the time to browse the SO questions & answer them. Makes the world a nicer place :)

Comment: @dieghernan thank you very much for your answer :)! and thank you to Mr Lacko for developing the function!